# Is it possible save reference to dynamic component and update it @Input/@Output later?

Tags: javascript, angular, contenteditable, angular6, angular-dynamic-components

I am working with contenteditable div. And i want to insert into it component when user press 'shift+2'. On keydown i am creating dynamic component like this:

```
addComponent(uuid: string) {
    const component = BodyVariableComponent;
    // Here is i want to save component ref into variable:
    this.variableComponentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(component)
      .create(this.injector);
    this.variableComponentRef.instance.uuid = uuid;
    this.variableComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.appRef.attachView(this.variableComponentRef.hostView);
    const domElem = <HTMLElement>(<EmbeddedViewRef<BodyVariableComponent>>this.variableComponentRef.hostView).rootNodes[0];
    // This function insert dom into carret position
    this.pasteDomElementAtCaret(domElem);
  }
```

And here is function that insert dom element into carret position.

```
 pasteDomElementAtCaret(domElement: HTMLElement) {
    let selection, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      if (selection.getRangeAt && selection.rangeCount) {
        range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = domElement.outerHTML;
        const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        let node, lastNode;
        while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
        // Preserve the selection
        if (lastNode) {
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
            range.collapse(true);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And then i want to update this component by saved reference:

```
updateComponentTitle(value: string) {
    this.variableComponentRef.instance.value = value;
    this.variableComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

But this doesn't work. The component in dom is not updated. Is it possible to update it dynamically later? I can set @Input properties in `addComponent` during creation, but how to update it later?